# Totally imprimitive groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

Following [Neumann P.M., The lawlessness of groups of finitary permutation groups, Arch. Math. 55(6) 1990, 521-532],  we define totally imprimitive groups in a more general form as follows:

Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of Sym$(\Omega)$ for some countably infinite set $\Omega$. If there is a chain of proper $G$-blocks
$$\Delta_0\subset \Delta_1\dots\subset \Delta_i\subset\dots$$
such that $\bigcup_{i\in\omega}\Delta_i=\Omega$, i.e. there is no maximal $G$-block, then $G$ is called totally imprimitive. My question is:

Is there a totally imprimitive subgroup $G$ such that Alt$(\Omega)<G<
$Sym$(\Omega)$, where Alt$(\Omega)$ is the alternating subgroup of Sym$(\Omega)$?

Comment: I'm confused by your "i.e. $\Omega$ has no maximal $G$-block. If $\Omega=G/H$, the condition seems to be that there is an increasing sequence of proper subgroups $H_n$ with $H_0=H$ and $\bigcup H_n=G$. But this might happen while there is also a maximal proper subgroup $L<G$ containing $H$. Therefore, I don't understand what the definition of "totally imprimitive" is.

Comment: Is there any problem in Neumann's definition in the cited paper? Neumann separates the imprimitivity condition as ``almost imprimitive" and "totally imprimitive".

Comment: But surely ${\rm  Alt}(\Omega)$, and hence also all groups containing it, is $2$-transitive, and therefore primitive. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Looking at the paper, there is no problem in the paper. But it seems that there is problem in your question: P. Neumann never writes that the existence of such a sequence implies totally imprimitive. In addition, in this paper he mostly assumes that the group acts by finitary permutations, which is a huge assumption.

Comment: In [Cansu Betin&M. Kuzucuoglu, On locally graded barely transitive groups, Cent. Eur. J. Math. 11(7) (2013), 1188-1196] uses the same definition. Is it meaningful?

Comment: So by Derek Holt's reply, there are no such groups. I did not know that Alt($\Omega$) is $2$-transitive. Thank you.

Comment: I missed a very simple point, sorry about that. But it showed me that I should work on the groups not containing Alt$(\Omega).$